# data.table :convert variables to constant within an id

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following `data.table`:

```
dat <- data.table("id"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), "year"=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
                  "var1"=c(4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4), "var2"=c(4,4,4,3,5,5,5,4))
   id year var1 var2
1:  1    1    4    4
2:  1    1    4    4
3:  1    2    4    4
4:  1    2    4    3
5:  2    1    5    5
6:  2    1    5    5
7:  2    2    5    5
8:  2    2    4    4
```

I want `var1` and `var2` to be constant by `id` and `year` and replace those values that are not constant by the first observation within `id` and `year`.

Also I would like to do it with a function and that the argument can be a vector  of any size depending of how many variables I want to convert to constant.

```
constant <-c("var1", "var2")
id<-"id"
year<-"year"
fn_const<-function(data, id, year, constant){

}
```

Comment: "vector of any size depending of how many variables I want to convert to constant" please ellaborate.

Comment: For your main task, ``dat[, `:=`(var1=var1[1], var2=var2[1]), by=.(id,year)]`` should do the trick

Comment: In my case I really have a bigger data with more variables that I would like to convert to constant. So for example the variables could be constant=c("var1", "var2", .... "var10") and not just two as this example. That's why I will like to know how I could make this solution you gave more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
dat[ , `:=`(var1 = var[1L], var2 = var2[1L]), by = .(id, year)]
```

As a function you'd have to do something like:

```
fn_const <- function(data, id, year, constant){
  data[ , (constant) := .SD[1L], by = c(id, year), .SDcols = constant]
  data
}
```

Note that this won't assign to `dat`, so you'll have to use something like `dat <- fn_const(...)`, which is probably not ideal (making copies). Instead, why not eliminate `data` as an argument:

```
fn_const<-function(id, year, constant){
  dat[ , (constant) := .SD[1L], by = c(id, year), .SDcols = constant]
}
```

Now simply running `fn_const(id, year, constant)` will assign `constant` by reference to `dat` with no copies necessary.

TBH I don't really see any benefit of writing this as a function in the first place, except maybe to save space if you plan on doing this over and over.